Qiskit pulse with qiskit >1.0
I am experiencing some difficulties with Qiskit Pulse when upgrading to version 1.0. Specifically, I am trying to adapt this notebook. What I will ask here refers only to the first section (calibrating $\pi$ pulse).
This is the adapted code I did:
# 1 Introduction
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
import numpy as np
from qiskit import schedule
from qiskit import pulse                  # This is where we access all of our Pulse features!
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter      # This is Parameter Class for variable parameters.
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit, Gate
from warnings import filterwarnings

filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
filterwarnings('ignore', category=FutureWarning)


def get_qubit_freqs(backend):
    backend_defaults = backend._defaults
    if backend_defaults is not None:
        return backend_defaults.qubit_freq_est
    else:
        n_qubits = backend._configuration.num_qubits
        keys = [f'wq{i}' for i in range(n_qubits)]
        return [backend._configuration.hamiltonian["vars"][key] for key in keys]

# select backend
service = QiskitRuntimeService(
    channel='ibm_quantum',
    instance='ibm-q/open/main',
 token='MY_TOKEN'
)

backend = QiskitRuntimeService().least_busy(min_num_qubits=5)

# Backend parameters
dt = backend._configuration.dt

acquire_alignment = backend._configuration.timing_constraints['acquire_alignment']
granularity = backend._configuration.timing_constraints['granularity']
pulse_alignment = backend._configuration.timing_constraints['pulse_alignment']

# unit conversion factors -> all backend properties returned in SI (Hz, sec, etc.)
GHz = 1.0e9 # Gigahertz
MHz = 1.0e6 # Megahertz
us = 1.0e-6 # Microseconds
ns = 1.0e-9 # Nanoseconds

# We will find the qubit frequency for the following qubit.
qubit = 0

# The sweep will be centered around the estimated qubit frequency.
center_frequency_Hz = get_qubit_freqs(backend)[0]        # The default frequency is given in Hz

# scale factor to remove factors of 10 from the data
scale_factor = 1e-7

# We will sweep 40 MHz around the estimated frequency in steps of 1 MHz.
frequency_span_Hz = 40 * MHz
frequency_step_Hz = 1 * MHz

# We will sweep 20 MHz above and 20 MHz below the estimated frequency
frequency_min = center_frequency_Hz - frequency_span_Hz / 2
frequency_max = center_frequency_Hz + frequency_span_Hz / 2
# Construct an np array of the frequencies for our experiment
frequencies_GHz = np.arange(frequency_min / GHz,
                            frequency_max / GHz,
                            frequency_step_Hz / GHz)

# Auxiliary functions 
def get_closest_multiple_of(value, base_number):
    return int(value + base_number/2) - (int(value + base_number/2) % base_number)
    
def get_closest_multiple_of_granularity(num):
    return get_closest_multiple_of(num, granularity)

def get_dt_from(sec):
    lcm = np.lcm(acquire_alignment, pulse_alignment)
    return get_closest_multiple_of(sec/dt, lcm)


# Drive pulse parameters (us = microseconds)
drive_sigma_sec = 0.015 * us                           # This determines the actual width of the gaussian
drive_duration_sec = drive_sigma_sec * 8                # This is a truncating parameter, because gaussians don't have
                                                        # a natural finite length
drive_amp = 0.05

# Create the base schedule
# Start with drive pulse acting on the drive channel
freq = Parameter('freq')
with pulse.build(backend=backend, default_alignment='sequential', name='Frequency sweep') as sweep_sched:
    drive_duration = get_closest_multiple_of_granularity(pulse.seconds_to_samples(drive_duration_sec))
    drive_sigma = pulse.seconds_to_samples(drive_sigma_sec)
    drive_chan = pulse.drive_channel(qubit)
    pulse.set_frequency(freq, drive_chan)
    # Drive pulse samples
    pulse.play(pulse.Gaussian(duration=drive_duration,
                              sigma=drive_sigma,
                              amp=drive_amp,
                              name='freq_sweep_excitation_pulse'), drive_chan)

sweep_gate = Gate("sweep", 1, [freq])

qc_sweep = QuantumCircuit(1, 1)

qc_sweep.append(sweep_gate, [0])
qc_sweep.measure(0, 0)
qc_sweep.add_calibration(sweep_gate, (0,), sweep_sched, [freq])

# Create the frequency settings for the sweep (MUST BE IN HZ)
frequencies_Hz = frequencies_GHz*GHz
exp_sweep_circs = [qc_sweep.assign_parameters({freq: f}, inplace=False) for f in frequencies_Hz]

sweep_schedule = schedule(exp_sweep_circs[0], backend)

num_shots_per_frequency = 1024

job = backend.run(exp_sweep_circs,
                  meas_level=1,
                  meas_return='avg',
                  shots=num_shots_per_frequency)

frequency_sweep_results = job.result(timeout=120) # timeout parameter set to 120 seconds

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sweep_values = []
for i in range(len(frequency_sweep_results.results)):
    # Get the results from the ith experiment
    res = frequency_sweep_results.get_memory(i)*scale_factor
    # Get the results for `qubit` from this experiment
    sweep_values.append(res[qubit])

plt.scatter(frequencies_GHz, np.real(sweep_values), marker='x', color='black') # plot real part of sweep values
plt.xlim([min(frequencies_GHz), max(frequencies_GHz)])
plt.xlabel("Frequency [GHz]")
plt.ylabel("Measured signal [a.u.]")
plt.show()

However, I get the figure below as the result of my execution on ibm_sherbrooke quantum device:

Which clearly is not at all what I was expecting and it has nothing to do with the notebook results.
Can you help me? Maybe my function get_qubit_freqs is not properly working, but I have not found other method to get the qubit frequencies than that. Otherwise, I have not a clue of what can be happening.
These are the exact versions I have:
qiskit version: 1.1.1
qiskit_aer version: 0.14.2
qiskit_ibm_runtime version: 0.25.0
qiskit_dynamics version: 0.5.1
qiskit_experiments version: 0.7.0


    # 1 Introduction
    from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
    import numpy as np
    from qiskit import schedule
    from qiskit import pulse                  # This is where we access all of our Pulse features!
    from qiskit.circuit import Parameter      # This is Parameter Class for variable parameters.
    from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit, Gate
    from warnings import filterwarnings
    service = QiskitRuntimeService()
    backend = QiskitRuntimeService().least_busy(min_num_qubits=5)
    
    filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
    filterwarnings('ignore', category=FutureWarning)
    
    def get_qubit_freqs(backend):
        backend_defaults = backend.defaults()#_defaults
        if backend_defaults is not None:
            return backend_defaults.qubit_freq_est
        else:
            n_qubits = backend.configuration().num_qubits
            keys = [f'wq{i}' for i in range(n_qubits)]
            return [backend.configuration().hamiltonian["vars"][key] for key in keys]
    
    # Backend parameters
    dt = backend.configuration().dt
    
    acquire_alignment = backend.configuration().timing_constraints['acquire_alignment']
    granularity = backend.configuration().timing_constraints['granularity']
    pulse_alignment = backend.configuration().timing_constraints['pulse_alignment']
    
    
    # import numpy as np
    # lcm = np.lcm(acquire_alignment, pulse_alignment)
    # print(f"Least common multiple of acquire_alignment and pulse_alignment: {lcm}")
    print("backend name : {:}".format(backend.name))
    # backend_defaults = backend.defaults()
    
    
    # unit conversion factors -> all backend properties returned in SI (Hz, sec, etc.)
    GHz = 1.0e9 # Gigahertz
    MHz = 1.0e6 # Megahertz
    us = 1.0e-6 # Microseconds
    ns = 1.0e-9 # Nanoseconds
    
    # We will find the qubit frequency for the following qubit.
    qubit = 0
    
    # The sweep will be centered around the estimated qubit frequency.
    center_frequency_Hz = get_qubit_freqs(backend)[0]        # The default frequency is given in Hz
    
    # scale factor to remove factors of 10 from the data
    scale_factor = 1e-7
    
    # We will sweep 40 MHz around the estimated frequency in steps of 1 MHz.
    frequency_span_Hz = 40 * MHz
    frequency_step_Hz = 1 * MHz
    
    # We will sweep 20 MHz above and 20 MHz below the estimated frequency
    frequency_min = center_frequency_Hz - frequency_span_Hz / 2
    frequency_max = center_frequency_Hz + frequency_span_Hz / 2
    # Construct an np array of the frequencies for our experiment
    frequencies_GHz = np.arange(frequency_min / GHz,
                                frequency_max / GHz,
                                frequency_step_Hz / GHz)
    
    # Auxiliary functions 
    def get_closest_multiple_of(value, base_number):
        return int(value + base_number/2) - (int(value + base_number/2) % base_number)
        
    def get_closest_multiple_of_granularity(num):
        return get_closest_multiple_of(num, granularity)
    
    def get_dt_from(sec):
        lcm = np.lcm(acquire_alignment, pulse_alignment)
        return get_closest_multiple_of(sec/dt, lcm)
    
    
    # Drive pulse parameters (us = microseconds)
    drive_sigma_sec = 0.015 * us                           # This determines the actual width of the gaussian
    drive_duration_sec = drive_sigma_sec * 8                # This is a truncating parameter, because gaussians don't have
                                                            # a natural finite length
    drive_amp = 0.05
    
    # Create the base schedule
    # Start with drive pulse acting on the drive channel
    freq = Parameter('freq')
    with pulse.build(backend=backend, default_alignment='sequential', name='Frequency sweep') as sweep_sched:
        drive_duration = get_closest_multiple_of_granularity(pulse.seconds_to_samples(drive_duration_sec))
        drive_sigma = pulse.seconds_to_samples(drive_sigma_sec)
        drive_chan = pulse.drive_channel(qubit)
        pulse.set_frequency(freq, drive_chan)
        # Drive pulse samples
        pulse.play(pulse.Gaussian(duration=drive_duration,
                                  sigma=drive_sigma,
                                  amp=drive_amp,
                                  name='freq_sweep_excitation_pulse'), drive_chan)
    
    sweep_gate = Gate("sweep", 1, [freq])
    
    qc_sweep = QuantumCircuit(1, 1)
    
    qc_sweep.append(sweep_gate, [0])
    qc_sweep.measure(0, 0)
    qc_sweep.add_calibration(sweep_gate, (0,), sweep_sched, [freq])
    
    # Create the frequency settings for the sweep (MUST BE IN HZ)
    frequencies_Hz = frequencies_GHz*GHz
    exp_sweep_circs = [qc_sweep.assign_parameters({freq: f}, inplace=False) for f in frequencies_Hz]
    
    sweep_schedule = schedule(exp_sweep_circs[0], backend)
    
    num_shots_per_frequency = 1024
    
    job = backend.run(exp_sweep_circs,
                      meas_level=1,
                      meas_return='avg',
                      shots=num_shots_per_frequency)
    
    frequency_sweep_results = retrieved_job.result()
    frequency_sweep_results = job.result() # timeout parameter set to 120 seconds
    
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    sweep_values = []
    for i in range(len(frequency_sweep_results.results)):
        # Get the results from the ith experiment
        res = frequency_sweep_results.get_memory(i)*scale_factor
        # Get the results for `qubit` from this experiment
        sweep_values.append(res[qubit])
    
    plt.scatter(frequencies_GHz, np.real(sweep_values), marker='x', color='black') # plot real part of sweep values
    plt.xlim([min(frequencies_GHz), max(frequencies_GHz)])
    plt.xlabel("Frequency [GHz]")
    plt.ylabel("Measured signal [a.u.]")
    plt.show()



Thank you so much!!
